# CP210x / CC2652RB (slae.sh zigbee) serial missing on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, serial-port

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

I just bought CC2652RB USB Zigbee (https://slae.sh/projects/cc2652/) but in my Ubuntu it doesn't create the `/dev/serial` folder.

This is the `sudo lsusb -d 10c4:ea60 -v` output

```bsh
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x10c4 Silicon Labs
  idProduct          0xea60 CP210x UART Bridge
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Silicon Labs
  iProduct                2 slae.sh cc2652rb stick - slaesh's iot stuff
  iSerial                 3 00_12_4B_00_23_93_25_9F
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              2 slae.sh cc2652rb stick - slaesh's iot stuff
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

It seems to me recognized... all right?

Edit

`sudo dmesg`

```bsh
[ 8907.724914] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 8907.876075] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 8907.876084] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8907.876087] usb 1-2: Product: slae.sh cc2652rb stick - slaesh's iot stuff
[ 8907.876090] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 8907.876092] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00_12_4B_00_23_93_25_9F
[ 8907.879007] cp210x 1-2:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[ 8907.881809] usb 1-2: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 8909.071926] usb 1-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 8909.072514] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 8909.072552] cp210x 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
```

Solved!

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove brltty`

brltty is a Braille TTY.

Comment: Thanks it helped me. You should answer you own question with your solution so that we can upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove brltty`

brltty is a Braille TTY.

`sudo dmesg`

```bash
[ 8907.724914] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 8907.876075] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 8907.876084] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8907.876087] usb 1-2: Product: slae.sh cc2652rb stick - slaesh's iot stuff
[ 8907.876090] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 8907.876092] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00_12_4B_00_23_93_25_9F
[ 8907.879007] cp210x 1-2:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[ 8907.881809] usb 1-2: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 8909.071926] usb 1-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 8909.072514] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 8909.072552] cp210x 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
```